# Best way to handle multiple PCINT in AVR

Tags: c, interrupt, avr, interrupt-handling, attiny

I'm testing some things on a Attiny85 and thought about the best way to handle the interrupt rutine. I know it is bad to have a lot of code in the interrupt handler, but I'm uncertain of any other ways to do this. I want my main program to sleep and wake on PCINT, the PCINT comes from multiple pins (rotary encoder A, b & switch and a receiving UART) so I was thinking just having a lot of code in the handler.

The code to determining which pin caused the interrupt, would look like this

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdint.h>            // has to be added to use uint8_t
#include <avr/interrupt.h>    // Needed to use interrupts
volatile uint8_t portbhistory = 0xFF;     // default is high because the pull-up

int main(void)
{
    DDRB &= ~((1 << DDB0) | (1 << DDB1) | (1 << DDB2)); // Clear the PB0, PB1, PB2 pin
    // PB0,PB1,PB2 (PCINT0, PCINT1, PCINT2 pin) are now inputs

    PORTB |= ((1 << PORTB0) | (1 << PORTB1) | (1 << PORTB2)); // turn On the Pull-up
    // PB0, PB1 and PB2 are now inputs with pull-up enabled

    PCICR |= (1 << PCIE0);     // set PCIE0 to enable PCMSK0 scan
    PCMSK0 |= (1 << PCINT0);   // set PCINT0 to trigger an interrupt on state change 

    sei();                     // turn on interrupts

    while(1)
    {
    /*main program loop here */
    }
}

ISR (PCINT0_vect)
{
    uint8_t changedbits;

    changedbits = PINB ^ portbhistory;
    portbhistory = PINB;

    if(changedbits & (1 << PB0))
    {
    /* PCINT0 changed */
    }

    if(changedbits & (1 << PB1))
    {
    /* PCINT1 changed */
    }

    if(changedbits & (1 << PB2))
    {
    /* PCINT2 changed */
    }
}
```

And then ofc inside each of the if-statements in the interrupt handler, there would be code handling something, like this code, turning on the Timer0

```
TCNT0 = 0; // Set counter to 0
OCR0A = SERIAL_BIT_TIME; // Call timer interrupt in middle of first bit
position = 0; // Reset position and data
TIMSK |= 1 << OCIE0A; // Enable interrupt for compare register A (timer interrupt)
TIFR |= 1 << OCF0A; // Clear timer interrupt flag to prevent it jumping directly there
PCMSK &= ~(1 << SERIAL_RECEIVE); // Disable pin change interrupt
```

or with the switch input, the code inside the if-statement would be

```
if (lightState)
{
    dali.transmit(ADDRESS, OFF);
    lightState = 0;
} 
else
{
    dali.transmit(ADDRESS, ON);
    lightState = 1;
}
```

Would this be a dumb solution?

Comment: Do not transmit anything in the ISR. Simple seet the flag and transmit in the "normal" program part. I personally prefer to use RTOS to handle it.

Comment: But if I set the flag and have the main program check for the flag, can I still make the microcontroller sleep and only wake on an interrupt?

Comment: You have main program. It goes to sleep. Interrupt arrives, the flag is set, program transmits the data and goes back to sleep. And again, again, again .......

Comment: Okay. Maybe I'm dumb, but I'm not sure how the main program would be implemented in such way. Would you just have the "check for flags" code after the sleep call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
volatile uint8_t flag;

int main(void)
{
    DDRB &= ~((1 << DDB0) | (1 << DDB1) | (1 << DDB2)); // Clear the PB0, PB1, PB2 pin
    // PB0,PB1,PB2 (PCINT0, PCINT1, PCINT2 pin) are now inputs

    PORTB |= ((1 << PORTB0) | (1 << PORTB1) | (1 << PORTB2)); // turn On the Pull-up
    // PB0, PB1 and PB2 are now inputs with pull-up enabled

    PCICR |= (1 << PCIE0);     // set PCIE0 to enable PCMSK0 scan
    PCMSK0 |= (1 << PCINT0);   // set PCINT0 to trigger an interrupt on state change 

    sei();                     // turn on interrupts

    while(1)
    {
        gotosleep();
        do
        {
            switch(flag)
            {
                case 1:
                    dosomething1();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    dosomething2();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    dosomething3();
                    break;
            }
        cli();
        flag = 0;
        sei();
        }while(flag); 

    }
}

ISR (PCINT0_vect)
{
    uint8_t changedbits;

    changedbits = PINB ^ portbhistory;
    portbhistory = PINB;

    if(changedbits & (1 << PB0))
    {
        flag = 1;
    }

    if(changedbits & (1 << PB1))
    {
        flag = 2;
    }

    if(changedbits & (1 << PB2))
    {
        flag = 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: So after one of the interrupts happen, this will go back to sleep and wait for a new interrupt?

Comment: After the interrupt it will handle what it has to handle and if nothing is to handle (imagine that next iunterupt arives after sei and before while loop check) it will go to sleep.

Comment: Oh waow okay, thanks a lot

Comment: Do remember that on AVR it is possible for a pin change to trigger an interrupt, but for the pin to then change back before the ISR reads it. This code will ignore these short pin changes, which is not always what you want. Waking from sleep extends the time period during which the pin can change back causing the change to be missed.